# If I print my variable, I will get four times a 1 instead of a number 4

Tags: php, for-loop, count, echo

I need to divide the two numbers and get the remainder. But when I try to print the remainder by using a for loop, it will return the total times 1 of the number, like so: when the calculation is 19/5, the remainder is 4 but it returns 1111

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="n1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="n2"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btnClick" value="click">
</form>
```

And this is my PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnClick'])) {

    $number1 = $_POST['n1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['n2'];

    if (!is_numeric($number1) || !is_numeric($number2) || strpos($number1, ".") || strpos($number2, "."))
    {
        echo "error";
    }

    elseif ($number1 <= 0 && $number2 <= 0 || $number1 < 0 || $number2 <= 0) {
        echo "error";
    }


    elseif(!$number1 <= 0 && !$number2 <= 0 || !$number1 < 0 || !$number2 <= 0){

    $answer = $number1 / $number2;

    $RoundedAnswer = round($answer);

    if ($RoundedAnswer * $number2 > $number1) {
        $Result = $RoundedAnswer - 1;

        $ResultRemaind = $Result * $number2;

        for ($i=$ResultRemaind; $i < $number1; $i++) { 
            echo count($i);
        }
    }
    else{
        $Result = $RoundedAnswer;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is you expected output

Comment: Why use `count()`?

Comment: I a not sure why this has an upvote. This is a silly mistake.

Comment: I just want the difference between the two numbers, but by using a for loop

Comment: wait I will show my whole code

Comment: just to with `$nG1 - $nU ` you get the value

Comment: *"I just want the difference between the two numbers, but by using a for loop"* ... I've got to ask ... why? What's wrong with `$nG1 - $nU`? If you're trying to get the difference between the two numbers, avoiding something like `15 - 19 = -4` (i.e. you want to know that the difference between 15 and 19 is 4 not -4) - you can just use the [abs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) function. `echo abs($nU - $nG1)` - don't need a loop then at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a counter for this. check below code:

```
$nU = 15;
$nG1 = 19;
$counter = 0;
for ($i=$nU; $i < $nG1; $i++) { 
    $counter++;
}
echo $counter; // showing 4 as you want. Counting for 15 , 16, 17 and 18
```

Or you can use php abs function to subtract two values as below:

```
$nU = 15;
$nG1 = 19;
echo abs($nG1 - $nU); // 4
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Why a loop, why not just....

```
<?php

$nU = 15;

$nG1 = 19;

echo $nG1 - $nU;

?>
```

Comment: because I wan't to knwo why it is not working, I know I can use echo $nG1 - $nU, but I just want to knwo why it is not working with a loop

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (19 % 5)
// outputs 4
```

or a more general version that also ensures whole numbers are used. Also uses the absolute value, because the result of `%` can be negative in PHP.

```
$remainder = (int) $num1 % (int) $num2;
$remainder = abs($remainder); // convert this to a positive number, regardless of sign.
```

`%` is the `modulo` operator, which gives the remainder of a division of two integer numbers.

The reason why you display four times 1 is:

```
$ResultRemaind = $Result * $number2;
for ($i=$ResultRemaind; $i < $number1; $i++) { 
    echo count($i);
}
```

`count()` gives you the amount of elements in a variable. `$i` is just a number, i.e. $i contains exactly one element. Therefore `count($i)` always returns `1`.

You use `echo` in your loop, so that means you print something (in this case `1`) as many times as the loop runs. You could do something like $counter++ in the loop and then `echo $counter` AFTER the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this....

```
<?php

$_POST['btnClick'] = TRUE;

$_POST['n1'] = '19';

$_POST['n2'] = '5';


if ( isset ( $_POST['btnClick'] ) )
{
    if ( ( ! empty ( $_POST['n1'] ) && ! empty ( $_POST['n2'] ) && ctype_digit ( $_POST['n1'] ) && ctype_digit ( $_POST['n2'] ) ) )
    {
        $total = round ( ( $_POST['n1'] / $_POST['n2'] ) );

        if ( ( $total * $_POST['n2'] ) > $_POST['n1'] )
        {
            echo ( $_POST['n1'] - ( ( $total - 1 ) * $_POST['n2'] ) );
        }
        else
        {
            echo $total;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error, inputs must be type integer!";

    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error, no button click!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the number differences then you can follow the followings:

```
$a = 15;
$b = 19;
echo abs($a - $b);
```

output 4.

OR

```
$a = (any value);
$b = (any value);
if( $a > $b ){
    echo abs($a - $b);
} else {
    echo $b - $a;
}
```

OR

```
$a = (any value);
$b = (any value);
$counter = 0;
if( $a > $b ){
    for ($i=$a; $i < $b; $i++) { 
        $counter++;
    }
} else{
    for ($i=$b; $i < $a; $i++){
        $counter++;
    }
}
echo $counter;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This OR Remove count function just echo $i variable

```
$nU = 15;
$nG1 = 19;
for ($i=$nU; $i < $nG1; $i++) { 

   echo $i;
   echo "<br>";
 }
```